# How should I get these buttons on the right of my table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this table:
[image]
How should I get the buttons to stay on the far right of each table row?

Comment: Some code would be nice :). Also, you can try to float:right or text-align:right

Comment: @ChrisG, I bet just float right can solve this ;)

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 1):

Try one code from below:

```
table td:last-child{
text-align:right;
}
```

or,

```
table td:last-child{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: Or you add something like OOCSS (http://oocss.org/) and add classes to elements. You are reusing code and keeping the overall code size down :-)

Create a class called fx. txtr (text right, and other useful classes as well)
´.txtr {text-align:right}´
´.txtl {text-align:left}´
´.txtc {text-align:center}´